# When re-sizing a textarea, if the parent element is a table, it expands to fit, but not when it's a div. Why?

Tags: asp.net, css, textbox, textarea, multiline

I have a textarea (asp.net multiLine TextBox) wrapped in a few nested divs. When re-sizing the textarea, it expands over all of the other elements. This is not the case when wrapped in a table, as it pushes the surrounding elements down and right to accommodate the re-sizing. How do I get this to work in a div?

I'm not a pro with CSS, but I've tried relative position on the contained child div, but this just makes the textarea hide all the other elements as it expands.  I can use a table, but I'm trying to get away from tables for layouts.

I've expanded outer divs to accommodate the content of inner divs with relative positioning, but it doesn't seem to work here.  Also, the overflow effect is not desirable.

Comment: can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Please provide jsFiddle with your issue. For example, `textarea` inside of `div` works. **Reference:** [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7AQfd/1/). ***You can revise the fiddle and press Update Button to create your version.***

Comment: ok, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/j_son_9000/w5TGu/9/) a quick example of what I'm trying to do... the textarea should push down and right the containing divs

Comment: @Sheikh Heera answer will work. Also, just using changing `width` to `min-width` and `height` to `min-height` will work too. Reference: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Szkw/). Feel free to Upvote and accept his answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same result (like a table) in a `div` using

```
div{
    display:table;
}
```

[**Here is a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/TbLay/).

Comment: **-1** The `div` is re-sizeable with `textarea` inside of it without requiring `display:table`.

Comment: Did you see my example, it's exceeds the fixed div.

Comment: If a div has fixed width and height then you can't do it, textarea will overflow the div.

Comment: @arttronics, [this is your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/7AQfd/2/) with width and height of the div.

Comment: Here is your [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TbLay/1/) without `table`. I agree with your point that if **fixed dimensions** are used then this is an issue, but the OP mentions that `table-like` performance of fluid `box` is required, hence `div` is not fixed since `table` with `textarea` isn't. The OP may only need to define `min-width` and `min-height`, but will wait to hear from OP before revising my jsFiddle.

Comment: To be sure, I will un-downvote you when your answer is revised. (It's interesting that ***fixed dimensions*** could be the issue at hand and using `min-width` and/or `min-height` will solve OP's Question.) Here is the [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7AQfd/3/) you gave me with those settings.

Comment: OP didn't mention anything about dimension and since he described the behavior of the textarea and div so it's clear that what could be the problem.

Comment: Also he mentioned he wants the table like behavior in div here `I can use a table, but I'm trying to get away from tables for layouts.` in his question.

Comment: I interpret the OP's context different from you, as information on dimensions is a logical conclusion based on the overall Question's context.

Comment: I just found this nice setting for a div: `resize: both;` [**Link**](http://dhtmlexamples.com/2011/01/20/creating-a-user-resizable-div-tag-using-css3/)

Comment: It's about div resizing with css3 (not textarea and css2) but thanks for the link. :-)

Comment: I will assume `resize:both` is exactly what the OP needs. The blanket tag of `CSS` is too general of a tag, and without any markup from the OP shown, one can only guess at the code allowed.

Comment: Well, then you should answer it :-)

Comment: @Sheikh - I ended up using a combination of min-height, min-width, and display: table to get what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @Sheikh Heera, read OP's message comment here indicating a collaboration of both our "guesses" are right, but my point all along is in my last Question comment that I provided with jsFiddle that does not use your method. ***I also told the OP to choose your answer since my comments are sufficient enough so the specific solution can be made.*** Cheers!

Comment: @arttronics, my answer was about how to get the table like behavior in div and I mentioned `You can achieve the same result in a div using` in my answer and for this I think I don't deserve a downvote from you because it's not a wrong answer in any way. Well, I was just trying to figure out that what exactly I made such a mistake for which I get a downvote. Whateer, it doesn't matter now. :-)

Comment: @SheikhHeera, I did not downvote you because it's a wrong answer.. I downvoted you because of what I wrote, which as you can see at the top of all these comments was: ***The div is re-sizeable with `textarea` inside of it without requiring `display:table.`*** I think you also are **not paying attention** to all these messages, as the 7th message from the top said **I will un-downvote** you once your Answer has a revision, as I can't do anything until that's done first. But as you say, ***"Whateer, it doesn't matter now."***. Cheers!